# Ant Design : How to add an icon to a tab?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I want to add an icon before the title of each opened tab. The source of icons could be bootstrap icons or other libraries. How can this be achieved ?

I am using antd library for creating tabs, which doesn't have the option of adding an icon directly. Below is the code snippet and here is the jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/6719phr3/1/

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { Tabs, Button } from 'antd';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';

const { TabPane } = Tabs;

const Tabbar = (props) => {

const [focusingPaneKey, setFocusingPaneKey] = useState('')
cons[openingPaneKeys, setOpeningPaneKeys] = useState([])

const openPane = (paneKey) => {
 setOpeningPaneKeys(oldState => {
  if (!oldState.includes(paneKey)) {
    return [...oldState, paneKey]
  }
  return oldState
})

setFocusingPaneKey(paneKey)
}

const closePane = (paneKey) => {
if (paneKey === focusingPaneKey) {
  const paneKeyIndex = openingPaneKeys.indexOf(paneKey)
  setFocusingPaneKey(openingPaneKeys[paneKeyIndex - 1])
}

setOpeningPaneKeys(openingPaneKeys.filter((openingPaneKey) => openingPaneKey !== paneKey))
}

const handleTabsEdit = useCallback((key, action) => {
if (action === 'remove') {
  closePane(key)
}
}, [closePane])

const { panes } = props
const keysOfPane = Object.keys(panes)

return (
<div className="tab-section">
  <div style={{ marginBottom: 16 }}>
    {keysOfPane.map((key) => (
      <Button key={key} onClick={() => openPane(key)}>
        ADD Tab-{key}
      </Button>
    ))}
  </div>
  <Tabs
    hideAdd
    onChange={openPane}
    activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
    type="editable-card"
    onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
  >
    {openingPaneKeys
      .map((key) => panes[key])
      .map((pane) => (
        <TabPane tab={pane.title} key={pane.key}>
          {pane.content}
        </TabPane>
      ))}
  </Tabs>
</div>
)
}

export default Tabbar
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TabPane accepts tab as ReactNode,

https://ant.design/components/tabs/

```
 <Tabs
  hideAdd
  onChange={openPane}
  activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
  type="editable-card"
  onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
>
  {openingPaneKeys
    .map((key) => panes[key])
    .map((pane) => (
      <TabPane
        tab={
          <span>
            <AppleOutlined />
            {pane.title}
          </span>
        }
        key={pane.key}
      >
        {pane.content}
      </TabPane>
    ))}
</Tabs>;
```

Try this

```
var x = {
  1: { key: "1", title: "Tab 1", content: "Content of Tab Pane 1" },
  2: { key: "2", title: "Tab 2", content: "Content of Tab Pane 2" },
  3: { key: "3", title: "Tab 3", content: "Content of Tab Pane 3" },
};

const map = {
  1: Icon1,
  2: Icon2,
  3: Icon3,
};

const getTab = (pane) => (
  <TabPane
    tab={
      <span>
        <pane.icon />
        {pane.title}
      </span>
    }
    key={pane.key}
  >
    {pane.content}
  </TabPane>
);

<Tabs
  hideAdd
  onChange={openPane}
  activeKey={focusingPaneKey}
  type="editable-card"
  onEdit={handleTabsEdit}
>
  {Object.keys(x).map((key) =>
    getTab({
      ...panes[key],
      icon: map[key],
    })
  )}
</Tabs>;
```

Comment: So the Icon that we want can be added in any other component and exported to tab ryt.?

Comment: yes, openingPaneKeys you can add components and use them directly.

Comment: Is there any possibility I can add the icon in the panes, so that each tab can have different icons that will be called from the panes directly

Comment: can you add openingPaneKeys data so that i can help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6719phr3/1/ check this link in the at the end I have panes details

Comment: const panes = {
  1: { key: '1', title: 'Tab 1', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 1' },
  2: { key: '2', title: 'Tab 2', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 2' },
  3: { key: '3', title: 'Tab 3', content: 'Content of Tab Pane 3' },
}

Comment: Can you please explain what you have done?

Comment: @ThomasDeepakKonreddy Is it working, I have mapped each id with Icon and on map i'm getting that icon from map and rendering.

Comment: I am looking into it.

Comment: Have you checked in the link that I have sent?

Comment: I have a doubt where should I define the icon, in map or in the <pane.icon />?